# How to fill entire div with background color

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to get a background color to fill the entire div in a child div in bootstrap, but I'm completely stuck. I want the right section to be yellow, but it's only highlighting the text in the div.

Here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hcgriggs/yjcrc91e/2/).

I know I'm missing something really obvious, but how do I get yellow to fill the entire `col-lg-6` div?

```css
.new-section {
  height: 100%;
  padding-top: 150px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #eee;
}

.yellow {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<section id="new" class="new-section">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-6">
        <h1>Section left</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-6 yellow">
        <h1>Section right</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: The div is not going to have 100% height, what are you seeing that it is not filling the entire div?

Comment: The entire div IS yellow...its just that the only thing in it is the heading - https://jsfiddle.net/yjcrc91e/4/

Comment: I don't see a problem... What do you actually want to happen? the second `col-g-6` div is already filled with the colour yellow..

Comment: @CaelanGrgurovic I want the entire left side of the section to be yellow, not just the content of the div to be yellow

Comment: For an element to get it's parents height, the parent must have a height set. So if you want `.new-section` to be 100% of its parent you have to add: `html, body { height: 100%; }`

Comment: @allcaps I needed to make `row {height: 100%}` along with the suggestion of @dippas and it works now. thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is happening because you are using `.col-lg-*`  with `.container` which only has `width:1170px`

So change `.container` to `.container-fluid`

See more info about containers in [bootstrap docs](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#overview-container)

```css
.new-section {
  height: 100%;
  padding-top: 150px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #eee;
}
.yellow {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<!-- New Exhibit Section -->
<section id="new" class="new-section">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-6 col-lg-6">
        <h1>Section left</h1>
      </div>

      <div class="col-xs-6 col-lg-6 yellow">
        <h1>Section right</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

or just:

```
.yellow {
    background-color: yellow;
    padding: 0 0;
}
```

Comment: This is unnecessary because background colour is applied to padding within a div. Also the use of `!important` should be avoided where possible.

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that `h1` has top and bottom margins that will be taken over by its wrapper and will *not* be affected by background-color since they are outside of the block element. You could remove the h1 tag and style the  parent container in a similar way (but using padding instead of margins):

https://jsfiddle.net/j33wz2o6/1/