# How to fill a division that includes a header to the left

Tags: html, css

So I'm new to HTML and it's my first question on StackOverflow so I'm sorry if it isn't professional. But to the point, this is my issue:

```html
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <div style="background-color: blue; width:100%; left:-10%;">
        <h1>My Cool Website</h1>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Please tell me how can i fill the header to the right to meaning how can i fill the whole line with the color blue

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fill entire div with background color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38017917/how-to-fill-entire-div-with-background-color)

Comment: Just use `* { padding:0; margin:0; }` in stylesheet that removes all the paddings and margins. And remover the `left: -10%;`.